# Laravel 5.3 adding data into two tables from the same form

Tags: laravel-5

I am quite new to Laravel and I would like to ask if there is any possible way to store only 2 form fields inside a table while all of the data are stored inside one table at the same time.

For instance I have users table where is store the data from my form .

```
     protected function create(array $data)
      {
         return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        "role" => $data["role"],

        ]);
      }
```

And this is my route.

```
     Route::get('users/create', ["uses" => "UsersController@create"]);
```

I have tried this and it is not inserting the data into the second table.

```
   protected function create2(array $data)
     {
       return User::create2([
       "name" =>$data["name"],
       "role" => $data["role"],

     ]);
   }
```

Route:

```
    Route::get('users/create2', ["uses" => "UsersController@create2"]);
```

What would I have to do to store at the same time only the role lets say and the name into a different table ?

UserController--> https://pastebin.com/8yjtLVar

RegisterController --> https://pastebin.com/DTiRJu3m

Answer (score 0):

In the function create2,write:

```
protected function create2(array $data)
 {
   return User::create([
   "name" =>$data["name"],
   "role" => $data["role"],

 ]);
```

}

Comment: Still not inserting the value from the fields sir.

Comment: What do you get in the Users table after calling both the controller functions?

Comment: I have two tables one users and one usersrole and in the users table I get all the data fine but in the usersrole table I get no data :/

Comment: newest answer might help!

Answer (score 0):

In the create2 function,write:

```
protected function create2(array $data)
{
  return Userrole::create([
  "name" =>$data["name"],
  "role" => $data["role"],
  ]);
}
```

Make sure that **Userrole** model is created for **usersrole** table in the database.